# Using fabric to run parallel task

Tags: python

I want to use the fabric lib to run parallel task via SSH , and I defined my script as following(running on Windows) :

```
from fabric.api import * 

env.hosts=[ 
     'builder@10.0.1.88:22', 
     'builder@10.0.1.80:22', 
     'builder@10.0.1.57:22', 
     'builder@10.0.1.58:22', 
     'builder@10.0.1.59:22', 
       ]      


env.password = 'xxxxxx' 

@parallel(pool_size=5) 
def test_task(): 
 space_info = run('df -h | grep space')
```

But when I run the script , it return the following errors , can any body help me what's wrong with it ? many thanks~

```
[builder@10.0.1.88:22] Executing task 'update_setting_remote' 
[builder@10.0.1.80:22] Executing task 'update_setting_remote' 
[builder@10.0.1.57:22] Executing task 'update_setting_remote' 
[builder@10.0.1.58:22] Executing task 'update_setting_remote' 
[builder@10.0.1.59:22] Executing task 'update_setting_remote' 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\main.py", line 745, in main 
 *args, **kwargs 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\tasks.py", line 412, in execute 
 ran_jobs = jobs.run() 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\job_queue.py", line 137, in run 
 _advance_the_queue() 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\fabric\job_queue.py", line 122, in _advance_the_queue 
 job.start() 
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 130, in start 
 self._popen = Popen(self) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 277, in __init__ 
 dump(process_obj, to_child, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 199, in dump 
 ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 224, in dump 
 self.save(obj) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 331, in save 
 self.save_reduce(obj=obj, *rv) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 419, in save_reduce 
 save(state) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save 
 f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 649, in save_dict 
 self._batch_setitems(obj.iteritems()) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 681, in _batch_setitems 
 save(v) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 286, in save 
 f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self 
File "C:\Python27\lib\pickle.py", line 748, in save_global 
 (obj, module, name)) 
pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function inner at 0x01FDD1F0>: it's not found as fabric.tasks.inner 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 380, in main 
 prepare(preparation_data) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\forking.py", line 488, in prepare 
 assert main_name not in sys.modules, main_name 
AssertionError: __main__
```

Comment: Are you running your script using `python` or `fab`. If you are using python, you probably need to have a `if __name__ == '__main__'`: to run the test_task()

Comment: I run it as  fab -f test.py test_task , and if I removed @parallel , it can run in serial successfully

Comment: I run the script under Python 2.7.10 + Win7 , does it mean Pickle can not run under windows?

Comment: Your example does not appear to contain `update_setting_remote` but no reference to `test_task`